# jQuery ui tabs anchoring, how to prevent it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I've built a tab navigation, but everytime if i try to access the a certain div using the url with the hash #, it would then anchor to the section, is there anyway to prevent it from auto-anchoring? This is happening in FF and IE but not Safari.

My code looks like this.
JS:

```
$("#header").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle' } });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#debt" class="debt">Debt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#car" class="car">Car</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" class="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#travel" class="travel">Travel</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="debt">xxx</div>
<div id="car">xxx</div>
    <div id="home">xxx</div>
<div id="travel">xxx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "it would then anchor to the section, is there anyway to prevent it from auto-anchoring?" makes no sense to me.

Comment: if i'm trying to go to a specific tab via the url, say http://www.goo.com/#car 
on page load, the page anchors to the div #car instead of page top.

Comment: Duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/8624531 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers parse a '#' followed by some string as an Anchor as you've noticed.

There's really two solutions:

1. Don't use hashes in your url

or

1. Change the name of your tabs. (car_tab, debt_tab, etc..)

If you change the name of your tabs you can keep your hash url and add some JS to show the correct tab.